# Android studio: changing imageview weekly

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to obtain create an app on Android Studio that displays an image on the main activity.  This image will change weekly.  I understand that this cannot be done by updating the application on a weekly basis.  How can I display an image and change it on a weekly basis without having to re-release the application?

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Glide-Library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just host your image on the web. Use `Picasso` OR `Glide` to load in your app.

```
 Picasso.with(context)
.load("imageURL") //new imageURL should same as the previous
.into(imageView)
```

You can update your image at any time on the web. Changes will automatically update to your app.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have tried this approach; however, I cannot change an image's URL.  How can I keep the same URL for a different image?

Comment: Just replace the old image with new one with same name of the old one.

Comment: Well I have tried that, but for example, when I save an image to my wordpress server it creates a URL that contains the date such as: "http://www.utrgvrider.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/DACAProtest3_1113web.jpg"     So I even If i erase the original image and create a new one with the same name the server will assign it a different URL

Answer (score 0):

You can stablish a date for each image. 
You try this:

1. Get the date with

   final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      String dat=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss 'GMT'Z 
      yyyy").format(calendar.getTime())
      System.out.println(dat);//"Sat Jul 23 11:03:36 GMT+01:00 2017"
   // or the format that you want (in your on create)
   // 2. Stablish the dates for example:

   `date1= //your date
    date2= //your date 
    date3= //your date 
    date4= //your date 
     .
     .

   //3. In your onCreate 
     if(dat>= date1 && 
      iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_name);
      }
      elseif (dat >= date2 && < date3)
      {
      ImageView iv= (ImageView)findViewById(v);
      iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_name2);
      }`